# StringEscapeUtils not handling utf-8

Tags: java, arrays, unicode, utf-8, apache-commons

I have a string like this

```
String incoming = "<html> <head></head> <body>  <p><span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">Ευχαριστώ (eff-kha-ri-STOE) Tι κανείς (tee-KAH-nis)? Mε συγχωρείτε.</span></p> </body></html>";
```

and I'm escaping it using the StringEscapeUtils

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(incoming);
```

The result is

```
<html> <head></head> <body>  <p><span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">\u0395\u03C5\u03C7\u03B1\u03C1\u03B9\u03C3\u03C4\u03CE (eff-kha-ri-STOE) T\u03B9 \u03BA\u03B1\u03BD\u03B5\u03AF\u03C2 (tee-KAH-nis)? M\u03B5 \u03C3\u03C5\u03B3\u03C7\u03C9\u03C1\u03B5\u03AF\u03C4\u03B5.</span></p> </body></html>
```

I've tried converting it to utf-8 by getting the bytes and it doesn't work, is there any way I could get it fixed?

here's what I tried:

String s = new String(escaped.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");

I've also tried a different library to escape the text still doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the characters such as single quote, double quote and backslash in your input `String` to be escaped, but you want the Greek characters to remain unchanged.

Unfortunately `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` will translate any text characters with a Unicode value > `0x7f` to their Unicode Escape equivalents. For example, your sample data shows that the Greek letter tau (`τ`) is escaped to `\u03C4` in the String returned by `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`. I don't know why `escapeJava()` does this. [Its Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-) states "*Escapes the characters in a String using Java String rules.*" but I couldn't find a formal definition of "*Java String rules*".

A simple way to to remove the Unicode escapes in the string returned by `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` is to call the `translate()` method for [the `UnicodeUnescaper()` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/translate/UnicodeUnescaper.html):

> Translates escaped Unicode values of the form \u+\d\d\d\d back to
>   Unicode. It supports multiple 'u' characters and will work with or
>   without the +.

So calling `UnicodeUnescaper.translate()` will return a `String` that:

- Leaves the escaped characters in a string, such as double quote, untouched.
- Replaces the Unicode literals with their Greek character equivalents. For example, `\u03C4` will be changed to `τ`.

The code is straightforward. Using your data:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.UnicodeUnescaper;

void convert() {
    String incoming = "<html> <head></head> <body>  <p><span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">Ευχαριστώ (eff-kha-ri-STOE) Tι κανείς (tee-KAH-nis)? Mε συγχωρείτε.</span></p> </body></html>";
    String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(incoming); 
    String greekChars = new UnicodeUnescaper().translate(escaped);

    System.out.println("incoming:   " + incoming); 
    System.out.println("escaped:    " + escaped);    // Quotes are escaped, and Greek characters are converted to Unicode escapes.
    System.out.println("greekChars: " + greekChars); // Quotes remain escaped, but Unicode escapes are converted back to Greek characters.
}
```

This is the output from the `println()` calls:

```
run:
incoming:   <html> <head></head> <body>  <p><span style="font-family: Arial;">Ευχαριστώ (eff-kha-ri-STOE) Tι κανείς (tee-KAH-nis)? Mε συγχωρείτε.</span></p> </body></html>
escaped:    <html> <head></head> <body>  <p><span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">\u0395\u03C5\u03C7\u03B1\u03C1\u03B9\u03C3\u03C4\u03CE (eff-kha-ri-STOE) T\u03B9 \u03BA\u03B1\u03BD\u03B5\u03AF\u03C2 (tee-KAH-nis)? M\u03B5 \u03C3\u03C5\u03B3\u03C7\u03C9\u03C1\u03B5\u03AF\u03C4\u03B5.</span></p> </body></html>
greekChars: <html> <head></head> <body>  <p><span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">Ευχαριστώ (eff-kha-ri-STOE) Tι κανείς (tee-KAH-nis)? Mε συγχωρείτε.</span></p> </body></html>
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Notes:

- Be sure to use package `org.apache.commons.text.translate` for `UnicodeUnescaper`. Older deprecated versions exist in `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate`. [This is a link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/download_text.cgi) to the download page for Apache Commons Text, currently at version 1.8.
- This is not an ideal solution, because it is calling `UnicodeUnescaper.translate()` to fix the mess created by `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`. There may be other approaches that are cleaner (by using an alternative to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`), but this way seems to work fine for your data.

Comment: Thanks, This works like a charm for my use case. It fixes the mess caused by escapeJava()

Comment: @orcluser [1] As quoted in my answer, [`UnicodeUnescaper.translate()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/translate/UnicodeUnescaper.html) will translate _"escaped Unicode values of the form \u+\d\d\d\d back to Unicode"_. But the string you are passing to `translate()` (i.e. "**f&uuml;r**") is not of that form.

Comment: @orcluser ...[2] Also note that the Javadoc for `escapeHtml()` states that it _"Escapes the characters in **a String using HTML entities**"_, and that is exactly what has happened in your example: "**ü**" was correctly escaped to "**&uuml;**". So your issue is unrelated to using German characters. Perhaps try replacing the call to `escapeHtml()` with a call to `escapeJava()` to resolve your issue if that is feasible?